# How can a server send data back to client after it closed a connection?

Tags: c

My server main thread run infinite while loop to accept connection from clients. After a server get connected with one client, it allocate a thread to handle client task, then close connection. After the task finish, I want my a allocated thread to send data back to the client. How can I achieve this? THank you so much.

1. client1 --connect--> server --ask--> thread A to do a task that client1 ask to do
2. close connection
3. Thread A finished the task, wanna send back result >>>> How?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this is possible? Have you seen an example where this is implemented?

Comment: Seem like I misunderstood everything. Thank you that you mention this. It is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't close the connection before sending the response back.

When a client opens a connection there are really two communication channels involved.  One is made by the client to the server, the second is made by the server to the client.  When you "accept" a connection on the server side, the remainder the client communication channel is also fully established.

By closing the connection, you destroy both channels.  If your server attempted to respond, the client has already received the close indicators, and has destroyed its ability to receive your data.

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way, do I have to close the connection after finishing a task? If I have to close, can I close it in a thread (passing filedescriptor to a thread)? sorry if this sound really silly. I do not understand it very well